# Help removing special characters from a value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this.

[image: RonTest Table]

The data in the "TestDate" column is a NUMERIC data type even though it represents a date. So, a value of "20200216" is February 16, 2020.

I am trying to mimic this programmatically by using the `CURRENT_DATE` function as my basis. I am then casting it as a VARCHAR and then trying to remove the "-" characters from the value. Then use that to compare to the data in the "TestDate" field.

```
SELECT "RonTest"."MemberID", 
    "RonTest"."TestData", 
    "RonTest"."TestDate" AS "TestDateVista",
    TO_CHAR(CAST("TestDate" AS VARCHAR ) :: DATE, 'Mon dd, yyyy') AS "TestDate"
FROM "RonTest"
WHERE CAST(regexp_replace(cast(CURRENT_DATE AS VARCHAR), '[^\w]+','') AS NUMERIC) > "TestDate"
```

The issue is that it is capturing the first "-" but leaving the second. This is the error I am getting.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "202002-21"
```

I could really use some help figuring out how to get both "-" removed from the value.

Unfortunately, the database is not controlled by me, thus I can not restructure the date appropriately within it. If I have missed a simpler method to query the field, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the 'g' from the regexp_replace command. Adding the g tells the command to remove all instances that match the regexp pattern not just the first patten. The statement below should work as you expect.

```
SELECT CAST(regexp_replace(cast(CURRENT_DATE AS VARCHAR), '[^\w]+','','g') AS NUMERIC)
```

The PostGre [regexp_replace documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/) has some good examples.

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thank you!